# strange daxpy Fortran in c

Tags: c

I'm still fairly new to c and i can't seem to understand this small bit of code.

```
void daxpy(int N, double alpha, double *x, double *y)
y=alpha*x+y
for (i=0, i<N, i++)
y[1]=alpha*x[1]+y[1];
```

i don't seem to know what daxpy function is doing or even its purpose. I know its probably something not very difficult. any help will be much appreciated. this was on my notes. I was just curious about what it was. I know the obvious things like daxpy is a function call. but  just need a small explanation on it

Comment: This isn't even a valid code fragment.  Could you add more code or at least more context?

Comment: @jwodder I added a little more but this was all I had on it

Comment: @johnmuddin: You still haven't shown real, working code.  Is this something you wrote down by hand during class?  Because there's no way in Tartarus this thing is from an actual program.

Comment: @jwodder it's just a code fragment so it's not a full running program, yeah i wrote exactly what was on the lecture board

Comment: `y<-alpha*x+y` <- how is this a valid C fragment even?

Answer (score 1):

I would think the actual code is like this:

```
void daxpy(int N, double alpha, double *x, double *y)
{
    for (int i = 0, i < N, i++)
        y[i]= alpha * x[i] + y[i];
}
```

This is because when looking at your code `y = alpha * x + y` does not seem to make sense. As `x` and `y` seems to be array, it should not work that way.
Furthermore, the following code is a loop, which I would think it explains the statement of `y = alpha * x + y` itself. And the number in the indices should be `i` instead of `1`, because it is a loop from `0` to `N`. It does not make sense to put `1` there.

So that function call is basically just to add every element of array `y` with it's corresponding value in `x` multiplied by a constant `alpha`.